# How to add characters to a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have strings who look like this 20110525 . 
[image: tableview]

how can i make to put '-' caracters  in NSString variable ? to let dates look like this 2011-05-25 ?
My second question is how can i sort the dates to make the table look like this 20110525 then 20110526  ?Help please . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using `sscanf(input,"%4d%2d%2s",&year,&month,&day)` to parse input string and `sprintf(output,"%d-%d-%d",year,month,day)` to format your date.

Comment: Of course, this requires converting back and forth between `NSString`s and C strings, so it's not quite a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the NSDate class to get the date, and use an NSDateFormatter to format the date the way you want.

Comment: @dec_newbie @ Gajet Thank you , but no one can help me to sort them is the MUtbleArray ?

Comment: Sorry, my mac isn't in front of me right now, but I would try creating an NSMutableArray from a bunch of NSDate classes that have been formatted, rather than trying to format a bunch of NSString class objects.